# Performing sequential write and block write using DD command for SD-card

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Ideally I would like to write stream data to my SD card for bench-marking purpose.

There are 2 types of data transfer commands for SD/eMMC:

1) Sequential-command - initiate continuous data stream

2) Block-oriented-command- Send data block succeeded by CRC

So my question is, by using the dd command below, will I be writing stream data(using sequential command) to the SD-card :

```
~# mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt
~# time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/file bs=4k count=200000 && sync"
```

If not , what is the alternative way to write stream data to SD card ?
Also, how can I perform Block-oriented-command for read/write using dd command ?

Reference: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/912497/jetson-tx1/emmc-5-1-slow-sequential-write/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The device node **/dev/mmcblk0p1** is for a block device. The `mount` command requires a block device. The `dd` command is for block transfers. Therefore the  `dd` example you show will perform block I/O rather than streaming I/O.  Unless you can find a special driver, Linux does not support streaming I/O with SDcards.  You probably should study the specifications from sdcard.org for stream recording.